# Android: reference to view outside fragment | gesture listener in fragments

Tags: android

I have a  TextView in a fragment where I want to set different texts when gesture is detected.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

The above code is used to listen for gesture, but it can only be used in an Activity class somehow, when I put `.onTouchEvent()` in a fragment class, it says cannot resolve method. 
Any idea how I can manipulate a view from outside the fragment or any ways to basically lsiten for gesture like I did in the Activity class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be far better encapsulation if you didn't have another class dive into your fragment's view and access it. Instead, have your fragment expose a method to do what you want and keep the specific knowledge of what is in your view local to the Fragment.
If there is an obstacle to that approach, advise and there's probably a pattern to help you over it.

Comment: I was thinking in the same way originally. However, I've searched all over the web but can't find a way to listen for gesture in a fragment while I used to be able to do it in an `Activity`, by `@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }`

Comment: You should post *that* as your question then, as there are definitely ways to listen for a gesture in a fragment. Be specific about what gesture and whether it should be for a particular view within your fragment, the fragment's root view, or what...

Comment: Edited my question, see if you have any counter measures to that? thanks

Answer (score 1):

To new question:
The fragment itself does not have an onTouchEvent, but any View does. So override the Fragment's onCreateView to find the TextView in question and add an onTouchEvent to it. Your onCreateView might just called super() or you might do your own calls to an Inflater or whatever, but here's an (untested) sample using super:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = super(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    TextView myTextView = myView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    myTextView.setOnTouchListener(new TextView.OnTouchListener( 
        // body of listener here...
    );
}
```

Comment: You can also declare the fragment itself as "implements View.OnTouchListener" and put the OnTouchEvent code in the Fragment. Then the above code just sets myTextView.setOnTouchListener(this);