# Android: reference to view outside fragment | gesture listener in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gesture

I have a TextView in a fragment where I want to set different texts when the gesture is detected.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

The above code is used to listen for gesture, but it can only be used in an Activity class somehow, when I put `.onTouchEvent()` in a fragment class, it says cannot resolve method. Any idea how I can manipulate a view from outside the fragment or any ways to basically listen for the gestures like I did in the Activity class??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: reference to view outside fragment | gesture listener in fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926958/android-reference-to-view-outside-fragment-gesture-listener-in-fragments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add touch listeners to views, so get the root view of that fragment, and add your listener with `view.setOnTouchListener(...)`